# How to protect createObjectURL with auth

Tags: reactjs

I have an API which returns HTML code. I want to render this in an `iframe`. To do so, I am using:

```
const blob = new Blob([htmlFromAPI], { "text/html" });
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
<iframe src={blobUrl} frameBorder="0" width="100%" height="100%" />;
```

However, this exposes `blobUrl` endpoint open to the public. How do I protect the `blobUrl` with auth so that only the logged in user can see this?

PS: if there's another way to render HTML code in an `iframe`, please let me know!

Comment: Can you use `srcDoc`?

Comment: @RajRentash Thanks for the reply. I don't want to use `srcDoc` as it doesn't have good support in browsers.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, or if I am missing something here. Can you add this under a condition where if the user is logged in you render `iframe` else show a different UI ?

You can call the authorization API in `useEffect` or `didMount` lifecycle

Comment: The best way to protect a resource is at the server level... Anything you do in the client side can be circumvented.  At the end react is nothing more than javascript

Comment: @YashJoshi This would work, but then wouldn't the generated blob url still be public?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I see, but how can I protect the blob url at the server level?

Comment: That would depend on what technology you are using on the server etc... That has nothing to do with react.

Comment: Dont generate the blob url if the user is not logged in.